# React alert issue

Tags: reactjs, native

Why I can send data in 1st activity to 2nd, but when I check data get or not adding alert then alert show before onclick

React native

```
 <ListView
   rowViewContainer
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
     enableEmptySections={true}
     renderRow={rowData => (
       <Text
         style={styles.rowViewContainer}
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About', { Paramlist1: rowData.title })}>
         {rowData.title}
       </Text>
     )}
     refreshControl={
       <RefreshControl
         refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
         onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
       />
     }
  />
</View>
```

or get
another activity

```
const listview1 = this.props.navigation.getParam('Paramlist1');
Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(listview1));
```

Comment: please be specific to your question.